# How do I schedule at Topic after it has already been created?

Tags: google-classroom

With students now learning from home due to the Corona Virus, me and my team are putting all of our assignments on our Google Classrooms. We are doing this by creating a Topic for each day. My question is:
Once I've already created a Topic and an assignment in Classwork, can I edit it to be scheduled? I don't want them all to get the work today, but I would like to assign it.

YES, I could have "scheduled" it when I created it, but we didn't. Our work is already posted within the Topic. I just want to be able to EDIT and schedule. 
|
THANK YOU!

Comment: Is this a programming question or a question about general usage of the Google Classroom site? If it is not a programming question this is the wrong site. Questions about general computer usage go on [su].

Answer (score 0):

Mrs. Gray, Topics do not have calendar dates. Questions, assignments, quizzes, and anything within a Topic can be scheduled, and can have due dates.

To change the scheduled time of it, either go into the the event from the calendar, and edit it. Or find the object (assignment, notebook, quiz, etc) and edit it's due date.

However, please note that this forum is for programming questions, and not for the general use of the product.

Have a look at these [help topics from Google](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/#topic=9049977).